# Using STDEV and RANGE to subset data to desirable subjects

Tags: distributions, standard-deviation, range

I am running several subjects through a mixed model regression and have encountered problems in which several of the subjects have an undesirable distribution for the specific study I am performing.  I wish to eliminate any subject with multimodality, uniformity, or strong skewness present in the distribution.

I have several hundred subjects for each procedure and am running an automated process (SAS), so I can't individually examine the distributions.  While playing around with the statistics and several repeated examples, I've noticed that the statistic x=STDEV/RANGE may give me what I'm looking for.  It seems that, as I look at the distributions, anything with STDEV/RANGE greater than 0.27 gives me the type of distributions that I want.

My question is, is there a better way to get only the subjects I want (roughly Normal, some outliers ok, but no multimode or uniform or strong skew)?  Is there any danger in the way I am currently thinking to do this?

Thanks.

UPDATE:  It looks like 0.26 may be a better cutoff, as it eliminates the uniform and bimodal distributions 98% of the time (at least in my limited testing).  However, it eliminates a desirable distribution 16% of the time.  Though I would rather delete a desirable subject than allow an undesirable one into the study, ideally I could have both...